# Why am i getting a missing method error for javafx.scene.layout.Background.fill in javafx for certain JDK 17/JavaFX 17 distributions?

Tags: java, javafx

I have some code which works fine using the Azul Zulu SDK (17.0.8+7) with FX bundled.

However if i take the unbundled Azul Zulu SDK (17.0.8+7) and reference the Gluon JavaFX SDK. I get the following error.

> Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: 'javafx.scene.layout.Background javafx.scene.layout.Background.fill(javafx.scene.paint.Paint)'

This problem persists in the Liberica JDK 17.0.8+7 FX bundled version as well.

It appears that the fill method is available in the Zulu JDK with FX bundled but not in the serparate Gluon Library or the Liberica FX bundled JDK.

Plese can someone explain please why this is and is it possible to achieve the same  without access to the fill method.

```
void setgradient(Pane bpane, boolean b, String color)
{
    if (b)
    {
        
        bpane.setBackground(Background.fill(new LinearGradient(
                0, 0, 1, 1, true,                      //sizing
                CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,                  //cycling
                new Stop(0, Color.web("#5e89b1")),     //colors
                new Stop(1, Color.web("#68a5de")))));
    }
    else
    {
        bpane.setBackground(Background.fill(new LinearGradient(
                0, 0, 1, 1, true,                      //sizing
                CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,                  //cycling
                new Stop(0, Color.web("#7d7b75")),     //colors
                new Stop(1, Color.web("#dedbd3")))));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the problem,

```
public static Background fill(Paint fill) {
    return new Background(new BackgroundFill(fill, null, null));
}
```

is a convenience method introduced in JavaFX 18. Not sure why version 18 of the FX is bundled in with Azul Java 17.0.8 ?

This code gets around the problem.

```
void setgradient(Pane bpane, boolean b, String color)
{
    if (b)
    {
        Background bg = new Background(new BackgroundFill(new LinearGradient(
                0, 0, 1, 1, true,                      //sizing
                CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,                  //cycling
                new Stop(0, Color.web("#5e89b1")),     //colors
                new Stop(1, Color.web("#68a5de"))), null, null));

        bpane.setBackground(bg);
    }
    else
    {
        Background bg = new Background(new BackgroundFill(new LinearGradient(
                0, 0, 1, 1, true,                      //sizing
                CycleMethod.NO_CYCLE,                  //cycling
                new Stop(0, Color.web("#7d7b75")),     //colors
                new Stop(1, Color.web("#dedbd3"))), null, null));

        bpane.setBackground(bg);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"Not sure why version 18 of the FX is bundled in with Azul Java 17.0.8 ?"* -> it isn't. `$ ./java -version` outputs `openjdk version "17.0.8" 2023-07-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.44+15-CA (build 17.0.8+7-LTS)`  and `$ ./java --list-modules | grep javafx.graphics` outputs `javafx.graphics@17.0.8`.  Probably, you were unknowingly pulling more recent JavaFX modules from some other location when you thought you were getting them from Azul.

Comment: You are correct it is using version 17.
I get openjdk version "17.0.7" 2023-04-18 LTS
OpenJDK Runtime Environment Zulu17.42+19-CA (build 17.0.7+7-LTS)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM Zulu17.42+19-CA (build 17.0.7+7-LTS, mixed mode, sharing)  
and 
java --list-modules | grep javafx
javafx.base@17.0.7
javafx.controls@17.0.7
javafx.fxml@17.0.7
javafx.graphics@17.0.7
javafx.media@17.0.7
javafx.swing@17.0.7
javafx.web@17.0.7

and yet the convenience factory method is in there even though the documentation clearly states "A convenience factory method for creating a Background"  Since : 18

Comment: Perhaps Azul Zulu backported the method for their distribution for some reason. Or, and I don't really know how it works between OpenJFX/Gluon/distributers-that-include-javafx, they're actually building OpenJFX themselves and are pulling from version 18, but version it 17.0.X while building to match the JDK version (I would find it strange if they did this).